# Rails 4 and returning JSON response: how to correctly append extra data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby, hash

I have a SQL query returns some data, here is some sample output:

```
[
    {
        "AccountCode": "111123456",
        "AccountID": 123456,
        "BalanceCurrent": "-8.0",
        "Phone": "123456888",
    }
]
```

This is a Hash with an array. There are times when there will be multiple hashes within the array. Just one in this example though.

As stated, this data comes directly from the database.

I have a `lookup_phone` method in my Customer model that runs the SQL query and then executed in the customer_controller.rb file like so:

`customer_phone = Customer.lookup_phone(params[:Phone])`

Now, I need to append some extra data to these hash(es) **that do not** come from the database, like so:

```
data = [
    :match_found => true, 
    :transfer_flag => false,
    :confirm_id => 2
]
```

This `data` variable needs to be WITHIN each hash object, not a separate hash object on its own.

Using a simple array `concat` or `+` always makes the data a separate hash object. I've come across some good posts saying to use `reduce` along with `merge`, but those are `Hash` methods, not `Array` methods.

If I try to set `data` as a Hash instead of an array, I get

`no implicit conversion of Hash into Array` when I try to do

`customer_phone.reduce({}, :merge)`

after running `customer_phone += data`

What is the proper way to append `data` to an existing Hash object?

Answer (score 1):

maybe combine `each` and `merge`

```
base = [
    {
        "AccountCode": "111123456",
        "AccountID": 123456,
        "BalanceCurrent": "-8.0",
        "Phone": "123456888",
    }
]

data = {:match_found=>true, :transfer_flag=>false, :confirm_id=>2}

base.each { |el| el.merge!(data) }
#=> [{:AccountCode=>"111123456", :AccountID=>123456, :BalanceCurrent=>"-8.0", :Phone=>"123456888", :match_found=>true, :transfer_flag=>false, :confirm_id=>2}]
```

Comment: So that works just fine in Rails console, but when I run it in the browser I'm getting `undefined method 'merge!' for #<Customer >`. Why would that be?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `attr_accessor` to your Customer model like this

```
class Customer
    attr_accessor :data
end
```

With your data array:

```
data_array = [
    :match_found => true, 
    :transfer_flag => false,
    :confirm_id => 2
]
```

Then, you can execute the query combined with `each function`:

```
customer_phone = Customer.lookup_phone(params[:Phone]).each {|e| e.data = data_array}
```

Access it:

```
customer_phone.first.data
```

To render json:

```
render json: customer_phone, methods: [:data]
```